# Quickly can't install in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, quickly

I am having trouble installing quickly in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
santosh@santosh-inspiron-15-3552:~$ sudo apt-get install quickly quickly-ubuntu-template 
[sudo] password for santosh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package quickly
E: Unable to locate package quickly-ubuntu-template
santosh@santosh-inspiron-15-3552:~$
```

Comment: Please help me .

Comment: What should you suggest to use to build ubuntu desktop application ?